# Elasticsearch - Enable fulltext search of field

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, kibana

I have run into a brick wall considering searching in my logged events. I am using an elasticsearch solution, filebeat to load messages from logs to elasticsearch, and Kibana front end.

I currently log the messages into a field `message` and exception stacktrace (if present) into `error.message`. So the logged event's snippet may look like:

```
{
   "message": "Thrown exception: CustomException (Exception for testing purposes)"
   "error" : {
      "message" : "com.press.controller.CustomException: Exception for testing purposes\n at
 com.press.controller....<you get the idea at this point>"
       }
}
```

Of course there are other fields like timestamp, but those are not important. What is important is this:

When I search `message : customException`, I can find the events I logged. When I search `error.message : customException`, I do not get the events. I need to be able to fulltext search all fields.

Is there a way how to tell elasticsearch to enable the fulltext search in the fields?
And why has the "message" field enabled it by default? None of my colleagues are aware that any indexing command was run on the field in the console after deployment and our privileges do not allow me or other team members to run indexing or analysis commands on any field. So it has to be in the config somewhere.

So far I was unable to find the solution. Please push me in the right direction.

Edit: 
The config of fields is as follows:

We use a modified ECS, and both messages are declared as

```
level: core
type: text
```

in file `fields.yml`.

in filebeat, the config snippet is as such:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths: .....
  ...
  ...
processors:
- rename:
  fields:
  - from: "msg" 
    to: "message"
  - from: "filepath"
    to: "log.file.name"
  - from: "ex"
    to: "error.message"
  ignore_missing: true
  fail_on_error: true
logging.level: debug
logging.to_files: true
```

For security requirements, I cannot disclose full files. Also, I need to write all the snippets by hand, so misspells are probably my fault.

Thanks

Comment: Please share your mappings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with the analyzer associated with your field, by default for text fields in ES, standard analyzer is used which doesn't create separate tokens if text contains `.` for ex: `foo.bar` would result in just 1 token as `foo.bar` while if you want both `foo` and `bar` should match in `foo.bar` then you need to genrate 2 tokens as `foo` and `bar`.

What you need is a custom analyzer which creates token as above as your `error.message` text contains `.` which I explained in my example:

```
PUT /my_index
{                                                                                     
  "settings": {                                                                                                                                    
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {                                                                                                                                
        "my_analyzer": {                                                                                                                           
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": ["replace_dots"]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "replace_dots": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            ". => \\u0020"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /my_index/_analyze
{                                                                           
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",                                            
  "text": "foo.bar"
}
```

The above example creates 2 tokens as `foo` and `bar` and same should happen with you when you create and test it with these API.

Let me know if you face any issue with it.

Comment: This will definitely help me save a few headaches down the line, so thank you.   Sadly, it has not resolved the issue completely as I cannot search for the space-separated words (such as "testing") as well. It seems that my fields are being converted to Keywords somewhere, yet I cannot pinpoint the place where. At the declaration time, they are all Text.

Comment: @erewien, can you share the o/p of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html api

Comment: Indeed, I can see it. There are really keywords everywhere. I cannot format it here, so I will append that to the question promptly.

Comment: @erewien, glad you could figure it out, I would suggest that you update the mapping and use the custom analyzer as suggested, however as changing analyzer of existing field is a breaking changes, hence would require re-indexing.

Comment: Ye, I did upvote long time ago, but for some reason or the other, I did not accept the answer. Probably a missclick on the tick or something. I accepted it now. Thanks for noting.

Comment: @erewien, Thanks for your prompt response, This motivates us to help community more.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Search indexes all fields by default, here you did not define the mapping hence all fields should be indexed by default.
Also for your case I doubt if the data is properly going in elastic search as the log doesn't seem to be proper json.
Do you see proper logs in Kibana if yes please send a sample log/screenshot

Comment: I cannot screenshot (or copy from, in fact) as the machine I have access to internet and the machine with Kibana are separate, so I cannot printscreen anything sadly and had to wrote the JSON by hand, so mistakes are probably by fault of mine. 

The Kibana is populated with the expected data and I can see the logs fine in both the table and JSON view. 

But only the Message field seems to work with fulltext search

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal - is "mapping" the "Level: core" "type: text" thing? because I can't seem to access much more. I cannot access the Index management with my account

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal - Can you send you current mappings done by elastic search. You can get mapping from kibana dev tools section using below command: GET index_name